# Selenium Webdriver cannot connect to service in Arch Linux

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, archlinux, geckodriver

Ok so this is in both chrome and firefox. I have:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11808880 Nov 26 22:04 chromedriver
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  6162368 Nov 26 18:08 geckodriver

$ echo $PATH

/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

I am running this under python2.7 I installed selenium via pip2, python2.7 by pacman (there are other libraries I need that have not made it to python 3 yet, stay focused). In idle2 I am getting:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.Chrome()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 104, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path)
WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service chromedriver

>>> browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 104, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path)
WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

>>> import selenium.webdriver.chrome.service as service
>>> s = service.Service('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
>>> s.start()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    s.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 104, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path)
WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

I also tried, taking a version of chromedriver into my home directory and pointing to it, then changing ownership to myself, both were no goes, the same issue exist for geckodriver, same errors, I am very confused as to what the hubbub is here, I did:

```
>>> browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/home/me/chromedriver", service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=/home/me/chrome.log"])
```

Same, error and it produced an empty log file, it never produced one prior and the geckodriver.log was always empty.